Will be starting as a Trainee soon but worried about my lack of experience in web dev domain
I will shortly be starting my first job at a service-based business. The company's main focus is on content management systems (CMS). Along with a few other new hirees for the same role, I will be joining as a trainee for a period of six months.
My lack of comfort with web development is the issue. I did not exactly lie in the interview because my projects were simple, but I do know more theoretical information and do not really have a lot of practical experience. That's why I wanted to know how I should proceed.
As I am new to corporate life, I am anxious about what lies ahead and am afraid of making mistakes. The company will provide our initial training. Which mistakes should I try to avoid making at all costs? To add to that, I did not lie on my resume; however, a lot of the interview questions were theoretical in nature, so they couldn't exactly judge the practical knowledge of the candidates.

Why do you bring up not having lied so often? Do you have reason to assume someone would think you lied? If they focused on theoretical questions, they intentionally did so.

Did the company give you any coding tests. during the interviews before they offered you the job ?

The definition of mistakes is that they are unintentional. Mistakes happen because we are human. They are part of life.
Check everything thoroughly before demoing it or transferring it. Dont be afraid to ask others what they think about which path you should follow.
When the mistakes are found, take ownership and fix them urgently.
If we knew all about a job, it would be boring and we wouldn't learn from it. The fact that it will be challenging, means you will be involved and you will learn.  This happens to all of us.
You always have Stackoverflow to ask questions when you are stuck. And there more than enough learning resources online.
If you want, you can try things at home on your computer first, before visibly taking the wrong path at work.

You will make mistakes, that’s not a dealbreaker in corporate life. Admit them, learn from them, move on and don’t fret about them.
Be proactively learning, have a good attitude, seek feedback on how to learn/improve from manager and peers. As a trainee you’re not expected to have all the skills, just to have the attitude and talent to get them.

To be clear about admitting mistakes, the cover-up is almost always worse than the actual mistake. The own it, learn from it, and move on from it is great advice.

You're a trainiee.  They are training you.  You are not expected to know everything before you start.

Which mistakes should I try to avoid making at all costs?

Learn from the CrowdStrike incident.  Make sure you have tested things before you hand them over to somebody else.  All software will have bugs.  But the earlier you spot them and fix the bugs, the lest harm and cost it causes.
